# For the time field of a table, how do I determine that it is continuous？

Tags: oracle

with PLSQL,I have a table with a large amount of data,One of the fields is time, which is continuous, for example

```
time
2022/1/1
2022/1/2
2022/1/3
2022/1/4
.....
2023/1/1
2023/1/2
2023/1/3
.....
```

When the amount of data is large, how can I quickly find the time data that generated the breakpoint
for example

```
2023/2/1
2023/2/4
```

2023/2/2 2023/2/3  These two data are missing data how can i find them quickly？

I thought of two methods. The first one is visual inspection. The small amount of data is okay, but the large amount of data is too prone to errors.
The second one is to process the time field, intercept the year and month for grouping, and then check the data of each month. whether the number of days is the same

```
time    count
2022/1   31
2022/2   28
...
```

But I don't think the two methods are very good. I don't know if there is a better way. If you can help me, I will be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as follows

1. Create a table which will store continuous dates.
2. LEFT Outer Join this table on the date column with the date column of your table which you are checking the date.

-- untested

```
Create table dt_master as 
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM) chk_dt
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 1000;

SELECT * FROM dt_master dm
LEFT OUTER JOIN CHK_DATE ON dm.chk_dt on chk_date.date_col = dm.chk_dt
WHERE  dm.chk_dt is  NULL;
```

Comment: Analytics like `LEAD` and `LAG` that others have suggested will show you that there is a gap, but this is the best way to see what the value of the gap is, especially if it can be larger than a single entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use analytic function LEAD(): a hole is when the LEAD(time) <> time + 1, assuming your time column is a DATE without hours, if not you may need to CAST/CONVERT and TRUNC.
You can also use classical holes detection with MATCH_RECOGNIZE if you want a report of the [start;end] of the missing ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG` or `LEAD`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT timecol,
               LAG(timecol) OVER (ORDER BY timecol) prev_timecol
          FROM table)
 WHERE timecol > prev_timecol + 1
```